# What is the simplest way to protect communication between an iOS application and a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, api, authentication, encryption

I have an iOS application that authenticates to a Rails application. The first time it authenticates, it needs to submit a username and password and in return the rails application returns a token which the iOS application can use to authenticate in further communications.

The information being passed between them consists of the user's email address and other trivial information, but nothing highly sensitive like financial details etc. I need a way to protect these communications.

What is the simplest way I can add this protection?

Comment: @Panagiotis Setting up SSL with Rails is nighmarish.

Comment: Bump. But you know, using a network tool someone can intercept your communication without even looking at code. The other way is implementing an encryption but as @Khôi mentions below is not recommended.

Comment: @Panagiotis I've been looking at using SSL for the last few hours but my stumbling blocks are: 1. I can't work out how to get it working locally so that both http and https work (I am running thin and it is only my API that I want to protect). 2. Using SSL in an iOS application means jumping through a whole set of hoops when it comes to submitting your application to the app store.

Comment: [Here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl) is a small tutorial, but you might also want to use [this](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) for your ios handshaking

Comment: @Panagiotis. Thanks. I'm using Restkit for iOS which is really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is a straight forward way to secure communication as is passes over the wire.  To reuse and token for subsequent communication can be done with oAuth.  You may want to take the approach that Facebook adopted in their iOS SDK.  They put up their login page in a UIWebView (HTTPS) and return the oAuth token for subsequent calls.

EDIT:  Since SSL seems to be "off the table" - why don't you just authenticate with Basic Authentication and have each call re-authenticate instead of using a token.

Comment: You mean use HTTP/SSL only for the handshake, then use oAuth? Why not protect it all with HTTPS/SSL. Is there a disadvantage?

Answer (score 1):

Get a trusted and valid certificate for your webserver and use SSL / HTTPS. That's what most people do.

I wouldn't recommend implementing your own encryption method.

Comment: My Rails application is hosted on Heroku, so I can piggyback on their certificate, but getting HTTPS working locally while still allowing access to the safe areas of my site through HTTP seems to be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems with SSL locally reminded me of this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)

When Ryan forced SSL, he mentioned that it would not work in the development environment (locally), only in production and testing. This issue is discussed around the six minute mark. It appears that if you deploy your app with ssl then it will work. This is also the case with Omniauth and using external providers. It does not work locally but it does when deployed.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. I'm kind of torn at the moment. Seems like a real nightmare to get SSL working locally, but I don't really want to wait until staging to solve any issues (and then I don't want to be solving them on staging).